# how to use a different template (index.php) in wordpress

Tags: get-template-part

I want to choose the best way to separate the mobile template and the desktop. Is this the right way?
If I put this code in the `index.php` file:

```
<?php if ( wp_is_mobile() ) : ?>
    <?php get_template_part('template-parts/mobile'); ?>
<?php else : ?>
    <?php get_template_part('template-parts/desktop'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: You can follow this approach for all individual template files. It's standard.

Comment: Pay attention to the tablet viewport, as wp_is_mobile doesn't trigger tablet viewports in some cases.

Comment: @user3135691 Is there a solution to this problem on tablets?